# Confused how to use numpy.delete()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is an easy question, but I find myself utterly confused.

I currently have a two-dimensional array `arr1` shaped (100, 101).

```
print(arr1.shape)  # outputs (100, 101)
```

I would like to delete one elements in this array `arr1`, the element

```
arr1[99][100]
```

which is the "last element" in these array.

How does one accomplish this with `numpy.delete()`?

I would think it is

```
import numpy as npo
arr2 = np.delete(arr1, arr1[99][100])
```

but this is incorrect.

Comment: NumPy arrays don't let you break the grid structure like that.

Comment: @user2357112 OK, so how do I remove that element such that I end up with an array shaped (100,100)?

Comment: An array of shape `(100, 101)` has 10100 elements. An array of shape `(100, 100)` has 10000 elements. You're overlooking 99 elements here.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, this is my mistake. Of course, I'm a fool. How would one delete all of these elements?

Comment: If you want to take off the entire last column, Mike Muller's answer shows you one way to do it. You could also do `arr2 = numpy.delete(arr, -1, 1)`, taking advantage of the `axis` argument to `numpy.delete`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clarify that you would like to delete the last column in your matrix (not an element)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OK, so how do I remove that element such that I end up with an array shaped (100,100)?*

Slice of the last column:

```
arr2 = arr[:,:-1]
```

Now:

```
>>> arr2.shape
(100, 100)
```

Comment: Of course! I was somehow confusing myself about matrix elements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is only 2d array, you can just do

```
arr2 = arry[:-1]
```